# dimension of a union of grassmannians

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, geometric-measure-theory

I'm working on a dynamical systems problem and have arrived at a naive question in differential topology? geometric measure theory?

I have a smooth path $\gamma\colon \mathbb R\to\mathcal G_2(\mathbb R^d)$ (that is $\gamma(t)$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^d$ for each $t$). I assume that $\mathbb R^d$ is equipped with the standard inner product. Now, let $V(t)$ be the collection of vectors in the hypersphere such that for $v\in V(t)$, $v$ is perpendicular to all vectors in $\gamma(t)$. Of course, $V(t)$ is the intersection of the unit sphere with a subspace of $\mathbb R^d$ of dimension $d-2$, so is a set of dimension $d-3$.

I'd like to show that the union of $V(t)$ is of Hausdorff dimension at most $d-2$. 
I already have a kludgy differential equations proof of this, but would like to find a nicer way to do this.

> Can anyone suggest a suitable framework for a nice proof of this kind of result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote by $S^{d-1}$ the unit sphere in $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$  $\bR^d$ and consider the   manifold

$$ X= \bigl\lbrace (v,t)\in S^{d-1}\times \bR;\;\;  v\perp \gamma(t)\;\bigr\rbrace. $$

The natural map $X\to\bR$  defines a fiber  bundle with fiber $S^{d-3}$. The fiber over $t$ is the  the $(d-3)$-dimensional sphere   consisting of unit vectors orthogonal to $\gamma(t)$. In particular $\dim X=d-2$.

The projection $\pi: X\to S^{d-1}$ is a **smooth** map. According to the Morse-Sard-Federer   the image of the map $\pi$ has  Hausdorff dimension at most $\dim X=d-2$.  (For more details about  the Morse-Sard-Federer theorem see Theorem 3.4.3 in Federer's book *Geometric Measure Theory*.)